# Прокрутка ScrollView (с webView внутри) на заданное значение

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview, прокрутка

Пытаюсь прокрутить ScrollView на заданное значение, но что то ничего не работает

Вот код:

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Активити:

```
ScrollView sv;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        sv.scrollBy(0, +50);
}
```

UPD: поменял `sv.scrollBy(0, +50);` на `sv.scrollBy(0, -50);` но все так же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оборачивать `WebView` в `ScrollView` нет необходимости, т.к. `WebView` имеет свой скроллер. Проблема заключается в том, что вы пытаетесь прокрутить вид, когда он ещё пустой. Убедится в этом легко через консоль `Logcat`а:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // для краткости создаем всё в коде
        WebView myWebView = new WebView(this);
        myWebView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        ));
        setContentView(myWebView);

        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        // убеждаемся в том, что высота виджета равна нулю
        Log.d("qwerty", "onCreate: height " + myWebView.getHeight());
    }
```

Существует множество способов определения момента, когда прокрутка становится возможной, и каждый из них имеет свои плюсы и минусы. Приведу только два, на мой взгляд самых удачных.

### Первый способ:

Подключаем свой `WebViewClient` и ловим событие `PageFinished`

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView myWebView = new WebView(this);
        myWebView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        ));
        setContentView(myWebView);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            // убеждаемся в том, что высота виджета не нулевая
            Log.d("qwerty", "onPageFinished: height " + view.getHeight());

            // работает начиная с Android 4.4 (API level 19)
            view.scrollTo(0, 1000);
        }
    }
```

К минусам можно отнести то, что метод работает только с относительно новыми версиями (Android 4.4 и выше). К плюсам - минимальное "хирургическое" вмешательство.

### Второй способ

Создаем свой `WebView`, определяем в `LayoutParams` высоту по содержимому (`WRAP_CONTENT`) и ловим событие `SizeChanged`

```java
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView myWebView = new WebView(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int ow, int oh) {
                super.onSizeChanged(w, h, ow, oh);
                if (h > 0) scrollTo(0, 1000);
            }
        };

        myWebView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT // <<-- это важный момент
        ));
        setContentView(myWebView);

        final String url = "file:///android_asset/index.html";
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Этот метод работает практически со всеми версиями, но накладывает ограничение на возможности разметки, т.к. не работает с параметром высоты `MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек! А я уже костыль написал - отключил у WebView прокрутку и отлавливал прокрутку ScrollView. Но Ваши способы прямо таки элегантны!